# check if variable is present by Reflection in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, reflection

I defined a variable in JSP `boolean isPresent = false` then in an included JSP I wrote code to check if this variable is present or not but getting NoSuchFieldException.

```
Class thisClass = this.getClass();
try {
    Field field = thisClass.getDeclaredField("isPresent");
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    //ToDo
}
```

Wondering what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you define it with:

```
<%
    boolean isPresent = false;
%>
```

the variable is defined in the method _jspService of the servlet generated from your JSP, like this:

```
  public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

    PageContext pageContext = null;
    HttpSession session = null;
    ServletContext application = null;
    ServletConfig config = null;
    JspWriter out = null;
    Object page = this;
    JspWriter _jspx_out = null;
    PageContext _jspx_page_context = null;


    try {
      /// more code

    boolean isPresent = false;
```

But if you change the declaration of variable to this:

```
 <%!
     boolean isPresent = false;
 %>
```

it will work !!

Servlet generated now:

```
public final class testing_jsp extends org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
    implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent {

    boolean isPresent = false;
```

**As you can see now the variable is scope class and NOT method scope**